# Is There A Way To Get A Boolean Value And Pass Validation With Backbone Forms

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-forms

I have a [Backbone.Forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) editor which is a select menu with `true` and `false` options. When I convert the string value to boolean and return that in the `getValue()` method validation fails. I'm guessing because we are returning false. Also the underlying model always sets the attribute as true because of the string value (thus the reason for boolean).

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    Backbone.Form.editors.BooleanSelect = Backbone.Form.editors.Select.extend({
        initialize: function(options) {
            options.schema.options = [
                { val: 'true', label: 'Yes' },
                { val: 'false', label: 'No' }
            ];
            Backbone.Form.editors.Select.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
        },
        getValue: function() {
            return this.$el.val() === 'true' ? true : false;
        },
        setValue: function(value) {
            this.$el.val(value);
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Why are you using a `<select>` input when you should be using a `<input type="checkbox">`?

Comment: Because that's they way I'm doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the validate() method (defined in Backbone.Form.editors.Base), that should fix it